# Script weekday daily job in cron.yaml on GAE (GCP)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

Just tested a scheduling service over GAE + Cron + PubSub. The Endpoint is .NET Web API. It works fine except some setting requirement in `cron.yaml`.

Reference is [How to Schedule (Cron) Jobs with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html?m=1)

My cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: Push a "tick" onto pubsub every day. Every tues,wed,thurs,fri,sat 00:10.
  url: /publish/daily-tick
  schedule: every day 00:10
```

As you can see the script runs successfully every day at 00:10. 
[image: gae_task_queue.jpg]

2 questions are:

1. How I can script a daily job triggered only on the weekday ? (As
   description says)
2. I manually click "Run Now" on GCP > GAE > Task queues got also
   successful message but actually no Web API response came out for
   this kind of scenario. (Expect got an email). The cron log is like
   this:

   `protoPayload.taskName="f389b******************"
   protoPayload.taskQueueName="__cron"`

Any hint I can go to check? Thanks a lot.

Comment: To answer your second question, we would need to see your exact code. It's impossible to tell otherwise, as we don't have insight into the many components involved.

Comment: Create a different question if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a cron job only on weekdays you can define a ["custom interval"](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#schedule_format):

```
schedule: every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 00:10
```

Would need to see your code for the `publish/daily-tick` handler to see why you're not getting an email

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-cron/blob/master/appengine/main.py

Comment: This should be a separate question, with code posted here